# How to import file CSV to python and search data in CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, search, tkinter

I'm new to python. This is where I'm stuck. I need to import CSV to python and create a search engine that I need to locate exactly data of small or large bag by input information. I was trying put the information of state. If I want to put year such as 2015, how it could eliminate states that not in 2015 survey section? For example, I put 2015, in State box it won't appear any state of 2016 survey. Finally, how can this search engine give the user the exactly data of small-large bag sold which they search for through message window?
I really appreciate for your help.
[Here is the csv file link,](https://www.kaggle.com/neuromusic/avocado-prices)

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import csv
#Create the GUI
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Avocado Search Engine")
root.configure( bg = "khaki1")
def show():
    """Shows the data in cvs file"""
    global state_box
    global year_box
    with open("avocado.csv") as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_file:


            if state_box.get() == "Albany" and size_box.get() == "Small bag":
                print(row[8])


#State label
state_label= tkinter.Label(root, text = "Choose the state")
state_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
state_label.configure( bg = "khaki1")
#State box 
state_box = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(root, values = ["Albany","Atlanta","Boise"], state = "readonly")
state_box.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
state_box.current(0)
#Size label
size_label= tkinter.Label(root, text = "Choose the bag size")
size_label.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
size_label.configure( bg = "khaki1")
#Size box
size_box = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(root, values = ["Small bag","Large bag"], state = "readonly")
size_box.grid(row = 0, column = 3)
size_box.current(0)
#Show box
show_button = tkinter.Button(root, text = " Search", command = show)
show_button.configure( bg = "spring green")
show_button.grid(row = 0, column = 4)
#Quit
quit_button = tkinter.Button(root, text = " Quit", command = root.destroy)
quit_button.configure( bg = "red2")
quit_button.grid(row = 1, column = 4)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would recommend using pandas for working with csv.

Answer (score 0):

Use the pandas library.
For importing the csv into your python file use: 
df =pd.read_csv("full path to your csv")

For example df =pd.read_csv("C:/user/user/Desktop/mycsv.csv")

To get information based on a criteria consider using loc.

df.loc[df.(the column you want to use for comparing) == 2015]